Python sync docstring between script and module
I am making a script that might be run as a module, and want to sync the docstring between them, how do I do this.
In this example, I want all the different docstrings to come from one place so future edits do not need to worry about the keeping the descriptions inline with each other.
(Note: argparse is a built-in python library for parsing command line arguments, the only important part here is that it exists and needs the description)
#!/usr/bin/env python3
"""
My long description
"""

import argparse

program_description = """My long description"""

def main():
    """
    My long description
    """

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
    argparse.ArgumentParser(description=program_description)

How do I reduce the repletion on the docstrings so I don't need to change 3 locations when I change the description? (If it can be reduced to 2 repetitions I will still accept the answer if an answer with 1 repetition is not provided)

In this code snippet module docstring is used in ArgumentParser and main, that can be checked by print(main.__doc__). However, main.__doc__ may not appear in syntax hints in IDEs.
"""
My long description
"""

import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description=__doc__)

def main():
    parser.parse_args()

main.__doc__ = __doc__


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()


This works for the module and argparse, which are the 2 I was most concerned about. main() still does not have a docstring according to the IDE though. From the reading I did else where this is due to the fact the the code would need to be run for the line main.__doc__ = __doc__ to work.
If nothing better arrives in the next few days, I will accept this answer, thanks.

@Lincoln yes, IDEs don't like dynamic docstrings.

Try This:

# Store description in a variable
program_description = "your description here"

# Set docstring for the module
__doc__ = program_description

def main():
    # Set docstring for the function
    main.__doc__ = program_description

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
    argparse.ArgumentParser(description = program_description)


'''
# if __name__ == "__main__":
#     main()
#     parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description = program_description)
'''


This has syntax error and even when fixed will not work. Please test before posting.

@makukha Yup, your solution is better, I don't have my code editor open atm my bad.

I tried this. The program will run like this, but my language server (the default for vscode) cannot recognize the docstring and will never show it, making the docstring useless.
